# Yii2 query error

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have this query in yii2 :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `agencias` 
    LEFT JOIN `responsables` `rsp` 
        ON `agencias`.`responsable` = `rsp`.`responsable_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `receptores` `rec` 
        ON `agencias`.`receptor` = `rec`.`receptor_id` 
WHERE (`nombre` LIKE '%pru%') 
    AND (nombres LIKE "%%" or apellidos LIKE "%%")
```

But i get the message 'Column 'nombre' in where clause is ambiguous'
i know how to fix this error setting an alias for the where conditions but dont know how to this is in yii2 activequery.

So the question is how i can set aliases for the where conditions to get a query like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `agencias` 
    LEFT JOIN `responsables` `rsp` 
        ON `agencias`.`responsable` = `rsp`.`responsable_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `receptores` `rec` 
        ON `agencias`.`receptor` = `rec`.`receptor_id` 
WHERE (`nombre` LIKE '%pru%') as alias1 
    AND (nombres LIKE "%%" or apellidos LIKE "%%") alias 2
```

Comment: Did you try adding `agencias.` before `nombre`? (considering this column is indeed in the `agencias` table)

Comment: yes, and it doesn't change the result because it still bring the name(nombre) of agencias and the name(nombre) of receptor, so there is where the problem happends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prefix the `nombre` field in the `WHERE` clause with the right table alias. Suppose you're filtering based on the `nombre` field in `responsables`, then your query should be :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `agencias` 
    LEFT JOIN `responsables` `rsp` 
        ON `agencias`.`responsable` = `rsp`.`responsable_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `receptores` `rec` 
        ON `agencias`.`receptor` = `rec`.`receptor_id` 
WHERE (`rsp`.`nombre` LIKE '%pru%') 
    AND (`nombres` LIKE "%%" or `apellidos` LIKE "%%")
```